# How to run multiple threads on RetrievalQA.from_chain_type?

Tags: python, langchain

Is it possible to run multiple thread on the same object of

question_answer = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(...)

I tried to run two thread, they seem to work ok.

But I cannot find from the documentation, is "RetrievalQA.from_chain_type" thread safe?

How to run multiple queries using langchain?

**THROWS ERROR: "Segmentation fault"**

```
import threading

def thread_function(name, qa, question):
    query = question
    res = qa(query)
    answer = res["result"]

    print("Starting Thread " + str(name))
    print(query)
    print(answer)

threads = []

for i, q in enumerate(questions, 1):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(i, qa, q))
    threads.append(thread)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```